# Using o-auth to authentify users on my API

Tags: laravel, oauth, jwt, lumen

I've got a project made of two websites:

- The front : A Laravel website without database and logic (just showing static pages and my javascript)
- The API : A project using Lumen/Dingo API with my endpoints, my database, my logic and my models

I want to allow my front to ask data to my API depending the user.

> Ex. I want to log the user, retrieve his friends, add some post to his
>   account, etc. (from the Javascript)

**What is the best solution?**

- Using an identification per user (using o-auth or JWT)
- Allow my front project to ask to my API then each javascript call needs to use my front without knowing my API) (In this solution I need to create routes similars to my API's routes)

Answer (score 0):

Identification per user is always a better solution as the claims can be decided per user, also in future when it is required to provide permissions to access API based on claims or roles, it becomes easy to give information using the claims and amount of access you can give to a specific user.

So the way it will work is:

1. There will be identity server which will be containing the list of users in the system, and also the clams and scopes per user.
2. The API project will trust the identity server, that means any token provided by the identity server can get verified.
3. Based on the token per user your API app can decide how much information you want to give to the user.
4. That way in future you can have methods based on roles, claims and users will be provided with only the information that they have access to.